# request.user.id is null in ModelViewSet

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

When I try to get active user id with request.user.id, it is always null:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
def instructor_detail(self, request):
    response_data = {}
    instructor = InstructorRepository.getInstructor(request.user.id)
    response_data["data"] = {"user_id": request.user.id, "detail": instructor.get("detail")}
```

When I test that method (getInstructor) with an id, it works. The problem is, request.user.id is always null, even there's no login problem related with JWT based auth.

What should I check?

Comment: It's a DRF issue, not a Django one (tags fixed).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. My method was under InstructorView, which doesn't force any permission classes.

I guess views without any permission class doesn't provide a request.user data, is this true?

```
class InstructorView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()
```

So I relocated the method under another view with permission class:

```
class InstructorAdminView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser, )
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
```

Now I can access user id...but I still don't know the exact reason.